# SSL cert recognized by OpenSSL but not geventhttpclient

Tags: python, nvidia, openssl, ssl, https

I have an instance of an [NVIDIA Triton Inference Server](https://github.com/triton-inference-server/server). Then, there is the [Python's client](https://github.com/triton-inference-server/client/tree/main) which uses [geventhttp](https://github.com/geventhttpclient/geventhttpclient/tree/2.0.10) Python's package to perform the requests.

This is all deployed as microservices, so in one container I have the NVIDIA Triton instance running, and in another container I have the client from where I run the inference requests (from now on, the app).

The issue I found is that whenever I try to perform an inference request using the Triton client from the app, I get this error:

```py
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)
```

which is pretty self-explanatory. However, if I dig down a bit and use OpenSSL to simulate the connection with the following command:

```bash
$ openssl s_client -connect triton.host:443
```

it connects successfully (`CONNECTED(00000003)`) using the correct certificate. cURL works too.

Also, I checked that the certificate is installed correctly and is present in `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`.

Does anyone have any intuition of which might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

From [the project site](https://github.com/geventhttpclient/geventhttpclient/tree/2.0.10):

> geventhttpclient depends on the certifi CA Bundle

Thus it does not use the system CA in `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` like openssl or curl do. Instead it expects the certifi package to be installed in Python. Likely you don't have it installed.

Comment: Certifi is explicitly named in the [project requirements](https://github.com/geventhttpclient/geventhttpclient/blob/d1e14356c3b02099c879cf9b3bdb684a0cbd8bf5/setup.py#L45C13-L45C13) so it most likely is installed. It may be an old version though and be missing a specific CA certificate.

Comment: @PhilipCouling: or this might be behind a corporate proxy and the interception CA is only installed into /etc/ssl.